# Fixed-effects using demeaned data: Why different standard errors when using xt/reg?

Tags: regression, stata, fixed-effects-model, clustered-standard-errors

My question is equivalent to this post:

[Fixed-effects using demeaned data: why different standard errors when using -plm-?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46978/fixed-effects-using-demeaned-data-why-different-standard-errors-when-using-plm)

which asks for getting the same SE in time demeaned regression as in fixed effects. How can I do the same thing in Stata? Here is my minimal example:

```
* Load data
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/nlswork

* Set panel structure
xtset idcode year

* Drop missings
bys idcode: egen count = count(ln_wage)     
tab count                           
drop if count!=15   
drop if union ==.
drop if tenure ==.
mdesc           

* Regression with Time Demeaned Data
foreach var in ln_wage union tenure age msp{
bys idcode: egen m_`var'= mean(`var')
gen tm_`var' = `var' - m_`var'
}
* F(4, 925)
regress tm_ln_wage tm_union tm_tenure tm_age tm_msp, robust
estimates store ols_td1
* F(4, 85) 
regress tm_ln_wage tm_union tm_tenure tm_age tm_msp, vce(cluster idcode)
estimates store ols_td2
* F(4, 11)
regress tm_ln_wage tm_union tm_tenure tm_age tm_msp, vce(cluster year)
estimates store ols_td3

* Fixed Effects Regression // F(4,839) 
xtreg ln_wage union tenure age i.msp, fe
estimates store fe

estimates table ols_td1 ols_td2 ols_td3 fe, se
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stata actually does a more complicated version of the de-meaning transformation than what you have above. You can find what it does in pdf manual, in the methods and formulas section for `xtreg, fe`. However, doing that transformation will still not fix your SEs. The crux of the issue is that `xtreg` correctly adjusts for the fact that the means were estimated before you can do the transformation. When you do it by hand and not adjust, you're "cheating".

The simplest fix for everything but the intercept will be one of second model these:

```
xtreg ln_wage union tenure age msp, fe
estimates store fe

regress ln_wage union tenure age msp i.idcode
estimates store lsdv

areg ln_wage union tenure age msp, absorb(idcode)
estimates store areg

estimates table lsdv areg fe, se drop(i.idcode _cons)
```

which yields:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
    Variable |    lsdv         areg          fe      
-------------+---------------------------------------
       union |  .06866013    .06866013    .06866013  
             |  .02628532    .02628532    .02628532  
      tenure |  .00317153    .00317153    .00317153  
             |  .00206349    .00206349    .00206349  
         age |  .01436476    .01436476    .01436476  
             |  .00154084    .00154084    .00154084  
         msp | -.07369826   -.07369826   -.07369826  
             |  .02136424    .02136424    .02136424  
-----------------------------------------------------
                                         legend: b/se
```

With clustered and robust errors, this equivalence will go away because of different small-sample adjustments used by each command.

I would just use `xtreg, fe`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation. I was hoping to implement a new version of interaction double demeaning in FE manually in Stata. Like https://panelr.jacob-long.com/articles/wbm.html in accordance to Giesselmann, M., & Schmidt-Catran, A. W. (2020). Interactions in fixed effects regression models. Sociological Methods & Research